# I am unable to open Azure's VM port

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

What i have tried so far...

1. Created azure VMs both on Classic and ARM.
2. Created end points of classic and ARM machine(NSG) port:9000
3. Open allow port 9000 in firewall on Windows Server R2 Datacenter
4. Check port status on `check-host.net`
5. Default Port status (Remote Desktop) is open, other ports are closed.

This is how i have created my end point in azure classic VM & Make New Firewall Inbound Outbound Rules.

[image]

Test Result of My Custom Port (Closed) & Remote Desktop Port (Open):

(I'm going to add my second image as a link in the comments)

Sorry for improper way of screenshots..actually i am new here so i can post only upto two links.

Comment: Not exactly sure what's going on here but... There's currently a service outage - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/ - could it be that's the culprit (making changes to the VM would be a service management function, which is what is currently impacted) ? If so, nothing can be done here. If not: Please edit your question to show how you created the endpoints (or NSG).

Comment: Thanks for your reply david but... i don't think so there is any service outage issue linked with this because... I have check default port created with azure machine is open while all other ports created by me are closed.

Answer (score 0):

Endpoints are your friend.Checkout this article:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-classic-setup-endpoints/

Comment: The OP already mentioned creating endpoints (and network security groups).

Comment: @harram-butt can you try if you can open from 'Change Settings' option via 'Control Panel\System and Security\Windows Firewall\Allowed apps'? or add a new outbound rule from 'Advanced settings'

Comment: Thanks Shiham for your kind response... I have created my end points in same as describe in this guide.More i have added in-bound and out-bound rules  in firewall to allow listening on that port. but still port status is closed. Help me.!

Comment: @Shiham i have updated my questions.. & added some screen shot in it .. Kindly check it again. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a short post on how to do this a while ago for HTTP and HTTPS traffic.  I think the same process applies in your case:

```
• The Azure Management Console has to be used to setup Inbound and Outbound security rules.
• This is necessary, for example, to allow HTTP and HTTPS traffic thru to the Azure virtual machine.
• NOTE: The Azure virtual machine will likely be configured with the Windows Firewall on. 
    ○ If the Windows Firewall is on, then it also will likely need to be configured with rules to allow HTTP and HTTPS traffic.
    ○ In this sense, Azure has two firewalls:
        § One firewall managed via the Azure Management Console.
        § Another firewall manage via the Windows Firewall.
• For inbound security rules, the following settings were used to allow HTTP and HTTPS traffic:
    ○ HTTP:
        § Name: Port_80_HTTP_Traffic
        § Priority: 100
        § Source: Any
        § Protocol: Any
        § Source Port Range: *
        § Destination: Any
        § Destination Port Range: 80
        § Action: Allow
    ○ HTTPS:
        § Name: Port_443_HTTPS_Traffic
        § Priority: 101
        § Source: Any
        § Protocol: Any
        § Source Port Range: *
        § Destination: Any
        § Destination Port Range: 443
        § Action: Allow
• For outbound security rules:
    ○ HTTP:
        § Name: Port_80_HTTP_Traffic_Outbound
        § Priority: 100
        § Destination: Any
        § Destination Port Range: *
        § Source: Any
        § Protocol: TCP
        § Source Port Range: 80
        § Action Allow
    ○ HTTPS:
        § Name: Port_443_HTTP_Traffic_Outbound
        § Priority: 101
        § Destination: Any
        § Destination Port Range: *
        § Source: Any
        § Protocol: TCP
        § Source Port Range: 443
        § Action Allow
```

Comment: Thanks! i will try this..  tell me its goes same for Custom Port ? Like i want to create a port : 9000(TCP or UDP) with name GpsTrack_9000... will your code work? actualy i have gps tracker, which will send data on 9000 port. Now i have application running on azure VM and listening to data comming on 9000 port. But i received no data at this port while application in running mode... I checked my port 9000 its status was going closed.

Comment: @HarramButt I believe the approach should also work in for your "custom" port.